# How can i retrieve the radio button values in the code below

Tags: php, html, mysql

Also there is something wrong with the radio buttons as i can select all 4 radio buttons of same name however i should be able to select just 1.

```
<?php
    $numbs = range(0, 22);
    echo "working1 .$numbs[0]";
    shuffle($numbs);
    echo $numbs[0];
    echo "<br>";
    $idcount = 0;
    foreach ($numbs as $elements) {
        if ($elements < 19)
            $numbers = range($elements + 1, 22);
        else
            $numbers = range(0, $elements + 1);
        shuffle($numbers);
        $numbers[rand(0, 3)] = $elements;
        $numbers             = array_slice($numbers, 0, 4);

        $imgcarrier = $elements;

        $sql     = "UPDATE chemistry SET form_values='$imgname[$elements]' 
        WHERE id=$id[$idcount]";
        $idcount = $idcount + 1;
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            ;
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }


        echo "<img src='$imgname[$imgcarrier]' height='100' width='100'>";
        echo "$imgname[$element]";

        foreach ($numbers as $y) {
            if ($id[$imgcarrier] == $id[$y]) {
                echo "<input type='radio' name='$imgname[$y]' value='right'>";
                echo "$store[$y]";
            } else {
                echo "<input type='radio' name='$imgname[$y]' value='$store[$y]'>";
                echo "$store[$y]";
            }
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

i am trying to make a quiz where each time the order of questions is changed and names are not in order. i'm unable to retrieve the values of radio buttons using $_POST. names correspond to image names stored in database and radio buttons are options.the one correct option should have value 'right' for each name.

Comment: What is in $numbers, $id and $imgcarrier?

Comment: Open generated html and se what names do you have there

Comment: updated the code $numbers is an array which stores 4 options.
$imgcarrier is another array having all image names stored from database.

Comment: @u_mulder the values are dynamic.will change each time.

Comment: add a class to all of them and use the class selector